# JQuery horizontal accordion banner absolute positioning error

Tags: jquery, css-position, horizontal-accordion

The following code operates a JQuery based horizontal animation system.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    maxWidth = 700;
    minWidth = 65;
    normWidth = 192;

    var featspos = 0;   

    $('.featuredslider a').each(function(){
        $(this).css('left', featspos+'px');
        featspos += 192; 
    });

     $(".featuredslider a").mouseenter(function(){
         var featscur = $(this).index();
         $('.featuredslider a').each(function(){
            featspos = 0;
            $(this).animate({left: featspos},800);
            if($(this).index() == featscur){ featspos += 700 } else { featspos += 65; };
         });
     });
     $(".featuredslider a").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).css('left', featspos+'px');
        featspos += 192; 
     });
});
```

There seams to be an absolute positioning problem because as soon as the mouse enters any one of the pictures they all move to left:0px; Additionally the function to get them back again will not work either. They just sit there at 0px;

I have set up a reference FIDDLE so I hope this helps solve the problem.
http://jsfiddle.net/FzaxF/1/

Comment: What exactly do you *want* to happen?

Comment: Like this www.divethegap.com/update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FzaxF/6/

You had an `.each` loop in the `mouseenter` event when it should have been in `mouseleave`. I also reset `featspos` to zero at the start of the `mouseleave` event and added a `stop()` to interrupt the animation if the user moused out before it was done animating.

Finally, resetting the images was moved to a function to eliminate some redundant code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    maxWidth = 700;
    minWidth = 65;
    normWidth = 192;

    function resetter() {
        var featspos = 0;
        $('.featuredslider a').each(function() {
            $(this).stop().css('left', featspos + 'px');
            featspos += 192;
        });
    }
    resetter();

    $(".featuredslider a").mouseenter(function() {
        var featscur = $(this).index();
        featspos = 0;
        $(this).animate({
            left: featspos
        }, 800);
        if ($(this).index() == featscur) {
            featspos += 700
        } else {
            featspos += 65;
        };
    });
    $(".featuredslider a").mouseleave(function() {
        resetter();
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, Essentially though I am trying to recreate this: http://divethegap.com/update/ It is what we were going to use but it is overly complex and has not support for using -webkit and -moz where possible

Comment: That site is a lot more complicated than the problem you were trying to solve here. Still, I think you're on the right track. Good luck.

Comment: Right I have nearly got it working. Now all it needs is some way of cancelling the animation if the cursor moves to the next image http://jsfiddle.net/FzaxF/8/

Comment: @RobinKnight Try: `$(this).siblings().andSelf().stop();` (or `$(this).find('a').siblings...` as appropriate) -- http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/FzaxF/11/

Comment: @mblase75... Lovely stuff. Now we only have one more requirement. Ill put it up as a new question, but basically it is to allow the plugin to function using JQuery animate enhanced for webkit and mobile platforms. Nearly got it working, but encountering unexpected results. FIDDLE:: http://jsfiddle.net/8WmfQ/1/

Comment: :: New question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983236/jquery-horizontal-accordion-with-added-css3-functionality